# Android Service, WebSocket

Tags: android

У нас в приложении имеется некоторая проблема с оповещениями, у некоторых пользователей они очень долго прилетают. А это заказы, они очень важны, да и другие оповещения очень важны, например о изменении состоянии.

Варианты:

1. Посылать запросы раз в N - секунд. Например повесить на Service. Сильно он будет разряжать зарядку на телефоне?
2. WebSocket. Как я понимаю (до этого не работал с ним), правильная его работа - отсоединение подключении при отключении экрана? Значит информация не придет при отключенном дисплеи.
3. WebSocket. Можно не обрывать соединение при отключении дисплея. Как сильно повлияет на разрядку?

Чтобы данные прилетали в не зависимости от открытого экрана. Его использовать на уровне Application. А как лучше взаимодействовать с таким подходом? Читал EventBus поможет в таком случае

Может еще подскажите варианты?